# How to create a typewriter effect in HTML using CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm taking my first steps in programming. How can I get the loop for the Typewriter? I also wanted to assign an id to the h1 tag, because otherwise it counts all the h1s on the website

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // array with texts to type in typewriter
  var dataText = ["VISIBILITÀ.", "NUOVI INGAGGI.", "NUOVI FAN.", "PIÙ VISIBILITÀ!", "SUCCESSO!"];

  // type one text in the typwriter
  // keeps calling itself until the text is finished
  function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
    // chekc if text isn't finished yet
    if (i < (text.length)) {
      // add next character to h1
      document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i + 1) + '<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';

      // wait for a while and call this function again for next character
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
      }, 90);
    }
    // text finished, call callback if there is a callback function
    else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
      // call callback after timeout
      setTimeout(fnCallback, 2000);
    }
  }
  // start a typewriter animation for a text in the dataText array
  function StartTextAnimation(i) {
    if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        StartTextAnimation(0);
      }, 20000);
    }
    // check if dataText[i] exists
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      // text exists! start typewriter animation
      typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function() {
        // after callback (and whole text has been animated), start next text
        StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
      });
    }
  }
  // start the text animation
  StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

```css
span {
  border-right: .05em solid;
  animation: caret 1s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo">hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // array with texts to type in typewriter
  var dataText = [ "VISIBILITÀ.", "NUOVI INGAGGI.", "NUOVI FAN.", "PIÙ VISIBILITÀ!", "SUCCESSO!"];

  function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
    if (i < (text.length)) {
      document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i+1) +'<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';

      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
      }, 90);
    }
    else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
      setTimeout(fnCallback, 2000);
    }
  }

  function StartTextAnimation(i) {
    if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined'){
      setTimeout(function() {
        StartTextAnimation(0);
      }, 20000);
    }

    // check if dataText[i] exists
    if (i < dataText.length) {
      // text exists! start typewriter animation
      typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
        // after callback (and whole text has been animated), start next text
        StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
      });
    }
  }
  // start the text animation
  StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work